# Redirect app traffic from my server to API hosted in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx

We have our app API hosted on our server at api.mydomain.com. Recently and due to growing demand we hosted our API on Google App Engine in order to scale when required. However, we can't change the API endpoint in our app since our app was built by a third party.

We would like to redirect traffic from our endpoint api.mydomain.com to the API we hosted in Google App Engine [project-id.appspot.com]. On our server we have nginx currently configured like such:

```
location /development {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass         https://[project-id].appspot.com/production;
    }
```

When we try to access api.mydomain.com/development it brings up Google 404 error page.

[image]

it seems like it is reaching the correct location but the host seems lost or something is not being sent over by nginx. Maybe Google filters something out. I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you setting `Host` header to `$host`? Try `proxy_set_header Host [project-id].appspot.com;`.

Comment: Thanks for replying @IvanShatsky. I had attempted what you mentioned, the problem that I get when I do that is a 400 bad request. Although I do see a 307 Internal Redirect in my network traffic.

Comment: Have you considered mapping your domain name to App Engine as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application) rather than using your server as a proxy?

Comment: remapping the domain isn't really something I can do. I have other services running on this server that do use this specific domain address.

Comment: Hi, can you access `https://[project-id].appspot.com/production/documentation` from your client?